# Symbolic differentiation with Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, differentiation

I'm trying to calculate Euler-Lagrange equations for a robotic structure.
I'll use `q` to indicate the vector of the joint variables.

In my code, I use

```
syms t;
q1 = sym('q1(t)');
q2 = sym('q2(t)');
q = [q1, q2];
```

to declare that `q1` and `q2` depend on time `t`.
After I calculate the Lagrangian `L` (in this case it is a simple link with a rotoidal joint)

```
L = (I1z*diff(q1(t), t)^2)/2 + (L1^2*M1*diff(q1(t), t)^2)/8
```

The problem is that when I try to differentiate `L` respect to `q` using `diff(L, q)`, I get this error

> Error using sym/diff (line 69)
> The second argument must be a variable or a nonnegative integer specifying the number of differentiations.

**How can I differentiate `L` respect to `q` to have the first term of the Euler-Lagrange equation?**

---

I also tried to write `q` simply as

```
syms q1 q2
q = [q1 q2]
```

without the time dependency but differentiation will not work, i.e. will obviously give me `[0, 0]`

---

That's what I've got in the workspace (I1z is the inertia of the link respect to z-axis, M1 is the mass of the link, L1 is the length of the link)

```
q = [q1(t), q2(t)]
diff(q, t) = [diff(q1(t), t), diff(q2(t), t)]
L = (I1z*diff(q1(t), t)^2)/2 + (L1^2*M1*diff(q1(t), t)^2)/8
```

---

If you want to run the full code, you have to download all the .m files from [here](https://github.com/igng/RI/tree/master/MATLAB/MATrices_LABoratory) and then use

```
[t, q, L, M, I] = initiate();
L = lagrangian(odof(q, L), q, M, I, t, 1)
```

otherwise the following code should be the same.

```
syms t I1z L1 M1
q1 = sym('q1(t)');
q2 = sym('q2(t)');
q = [q1, q2];
qp = diff(q, t);
L = (I1z*qp(1)^2)/2 + (L1^2*M1*qp(1)^2)/8;
```

---

## EDIT

Thanks to [AVK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42437853/5025931) I realized the problem.

## Example 1 (AVK's code)

```
syms t q1 q2 q1t q2t I1z L1 M1        % variables
L = (I1z*q1t^2)/2 + (L1^2*M1*q1t^2)/8
dLdqt = [diff(L,q1t), diff(L,q2t)]
```

This will work and its result will be

`dLdqt = [(M1*q1t*L1^2)/4 + I1z*q1t, 0]`

## Example 2 (wrong)

```
syms t q1 q2 q1t q2t I1z L1 M1
L = (I1z*q1t^2)/2 + (L1^2*M1*q1t^2)/8;
qt = [q1t q2t];
dLdqt = diff(L, qt)
```

This will **not** work, because `diff` expects a **single** variable of differentiation

## Example 3 (right)

```
syms t q1 q2 q1t q2t I1z L1 M1
L = (I1z*q1t^2)/2 + (L1^2*M1*q1t^2)/8;
qt = [q1t q2t];
dLdqt = jacobian(L, qt)
```

This **will** work, because `jacobian` expects **at least** a variable of differentiation

---

## EDIT 2

Seems that MATLAB's Symbolit Toolbox can't handle differentiation with respect to `q(t)`, so you have to use the **variable** `q`.

So using these as **functions**

```
q = [q1(t), q2(t), q3(t), q4(t), q5(t), q6(t)]
qp = [diff(q1(t), t), diff(q2(t), t), diff(q3(t), t), diff(q4(t), t), diff(q5(t), t), diff(q6(t), t)]
```

and these as **variables**

```
qv = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6];
qvp = [q1p, q2p, q3p, q4p, q5p, q6p];
```

solved the problem.

The whole code will looks like this

```
syms q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6;
syms q1p q2p q3p q4p q5p q6p;
qv = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6];
qvp = [q1p, q2p, q3p, q4p, q5p, q6p];

Lagv = subs(Lag, [q, qp], [qv, qvp]);
dLdq = jacobian(Lagv, qv);
dLdqp = jacobian(Lagv, qvp);

dLdq = subs(dLdq, [qv, qvp], [q, qp]);
dLdqp = subs(dLdqp, [qv, qvp], [q, qp]);

m_eq = diff(dLdqp, t) - dLdq;
```

Comment: `I1z` etc are undefined. Please post code we can run

Comment: Please also note that there are two types of derivative in the Lagrange equations: partial and total. Each type should be calculated in its own way, that is the reason why I had replaced the variables with the functions. The Symbolic Math Toolbox can not differentiate with respect to `q(t)`, so `q` must be a variable; but later, when we need to calculate the total derivative, it must be a function of `t`.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that it can't differentiate with respect to `q(t)`. Using `q1` and `q1p` as variables and then using `subs` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to differentiate L with respect to q, q must be a variable. You can use `subs` to replace it with a function and calculate
[image: ddt]
later:

```
syms t q1 q2 q1t q2t I1z L1 M1        % variables
L = (I1z*q1t^2)/2 + (L1^2*M1*q1t^2)/8
dLdqt= [diff(L,q1t), diff(L,q2t)]
dLdq = [diff(L,q1), diff(L,q2)]
syms q1_f(t) q2_f(t)  % functions
q1t_f(t)= diff(q1_f,t)
q2t_f(t)= diff(q2_f,t)
    % replace the variables with the functions
dLdq_f= subs(dLdq,{q1 q2 q1t q2t},{q1_f q2_f q1t_f q2t_f})
dLdqt_f= subs(dLdqt,{q1 q2 q1t q2t},{q1_f q2_f q1t_f q2t_f}) 
    % now we can solve the equation
dsolve(diff(dLdqt_f,t)-dLdq_f==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed the Euler-Lagrange Library in MATLAB, with a list of illustrative examples. you can download it using the following link:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/86563-matlab-euler-lagrange-library